# How do you prove something is the LCM of two numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, least-common-multiple

I am wondering if there is a proof validating the definition of the LCM. I know that the least common multiple of two integers, say $a, b$ is just the smaller number $n$, such that $a|n$ and $b|n$, but is there a proof that goes along with this?

Comment: If you want to check that $n$ is indeed $LCM(a,b)$, compute $GCD(n/a,n/b)$. It must be $1$.

Comment: This should be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not a proof of this. This is because LCM is just defined that way, just like how we define operations like multiplication, addition, subtraction, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the following statement:

Let $a,b\in\mathbb N$. Let $c = \frac{ab}{(a,b)} =: \operatorname{lcm}(a,b).$ Then:

- $c$ is a natural number
- $a|c$ and $b|c$
- For all $n,$ if $a|n$ and $b|n$ then $n\ge c.$

Comment: Is there a way to prove the last bullet point is true?

Comment: Yes. You can prove all 3 using well known theorems about gcd.

Comment: In fact, you can also replace $n\ge c$ with $c|n$ and the result will still hold